# How to check for RedHat (RHEL) minor version in rpm spec file?

Tags: rpmbuild, rpm-spec

Need to differentiate a package dependency between RHEL 7.2/7.3 v/s RHEL 7.4 and above. There is `rhel` macro available in rpm spec file but that evaluates to 7 for all RHEL 7.x and 6 for all RHEL 6.x versions.

I can possibly read `/etc/redhat-release` file and determine the minor version in `%pre` section but unclear whether that's too late to specify package dependency using `Requires` directive.

I tried defining a macro that reads `/etc/redhat-release` file and then using the macro like following

```
%define rhel_minor_version %(rhel_version_file="/etc/redhat-release";
if [ -f $rhel_version_file ]; then echo $(cat $rhel_version_file |
grep -oP '.*7\.\K([0-9]+)'); else echo 0; fi)

%if 0%{?rhel} == 7
%if 0%{?rhel_minor_version} >= 4
Requires: iperf3
%endif
%endif
```

However this macro gets evaluated on the system where `rpmbuild` is invoked to build the rpm package and not the system where the rpm package is installed. So doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Usually it works by requesting the _feature_ you need, which is provided by one RPM on one 7.x version and another in 7.y. This is set using `Provides` in the specfile, _e.g._ 7.y might have an RPM `compat_libyourlib` which is equal to what's on 7.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mechanism to specify weak dependency i.e. optional dependency in rpm spec file. This way if the package is available it’ll be installed else dependency will be ignored.
https://rpm.org/user_doc/dependencies.html

“Recommends” directive appears valid on Fedora but not available on RHEL
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1427674

After much thought I don't think it's possible to differentiate dependencies based on RHEL minor version without shipping different el7 packages for RHEL 7.2/7.3 v/s RHEL 7.4+ which is not an option...